# Use of “the” in between "most of ___ Earth's"

Tags: articles, determiners, qualifiers

In this sentence :

> New research suggests **most of Earth's heavy metals** were spewed from a largely overlooked kind of star explosion called a collapser.

Here *the* should be used or not between "most of ___ Earth's"? I'm asking about this due to the presence of “most of” - it's limiting here Earth's heavy metals.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [earth; the earth](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15360/earth-the-earth)

Comment: Here, I'm asking about the due to the presence of most of n it's limiting here Earth's heavy metals.

Comment: Are you confusing it with "most of the heavy metals"?

Comment: I’ve edited the question to include the information in your comment @ShubhamJha and retracted my close vote. Improving your question by editing to add more information is better than just responding in comments, because some people won’t read the comments.

Comment: Do you feel that “most of” makes “Earth’s heavy metals” a specific thing, so it requires the definite article? Or is there a different reason?

Comment: Can you quickly check your source to see whether the word "collapsar" is actually used? I think "collapser" may be a copying error.

Comment: What @PrimeMover said. It's definitely ***collapsar*** ([*here's*](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2019/06/190613121042.htm) the *Science Daily* link). So far as I'm concered, it's entirely a stylistic choice in this *exact* context where to precede ***Earth*** here by a definite article. See [*About definite article before “Earth”, “Moon” and “Sun”*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33282/) as asked on ELU many years ago.

Comment: @prime mover, yes..sorry, it's collapsar. And I'm confused here because we generally use *the* after using *most of ____ xyz* formation. Like:- most kids like chocolates vs most of the kids in my neighborhood like chocolates!

Comment: @ShubhamJha Yes, but then it's "most of ShubhamJha's chocolates", not "most of the ShubhamJha's chocolates ..."

Comment: @PrimeMover so the general syntax says that we remove the if we are using possessive noun or it is because of personal noun(pronoun)?

Comment: @ShubhamJha yes